# apache segmentation error

Tags: apache-2.2

I can't start Apache with the following errors:

```
[root@web]# /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: /bin/bash: line 1: 19232 Segmentation fault      /usr/sbin/httpd
[root@web]# /usr/sbin/apachectl -k start
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 102: 19919 Segmentation fault      $HTTPD $OPTIONS $ARGV
```

I use webmin control panel and I've already tried re-installing Apache from scratch. Can someone advise what else I should try to do? Many thanks.

UPDATE:

The only line is always written in the error logs which seems not to be very important:

```
[Mon Nov 14 19:00:09 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

UPDATE 2:

I've recently had the error below in the logs. Looks like some modules are incompatible, so I've just disabled these extensions: fileinfo and mcrypt in my php.ini. I should be able to start the web server without them.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0\nPHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

UPDATE 3:

```
[root@web]# file /usr/sbin/httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
[root@web]# uname -m
x86_64
```

Comment: Use the logs, lush. See `/var/log/httpd/error.log` and see if there is a more detailed reason for Apache crash. If not, try `httpd -D` and see what happens. Also please be more specific; did you recently upgrade your server software? Anything else happened? Did this server work before and only recently stopped working? No matter how gurus we are here at Server Fault, it's hard to answer if the whole question is around 5 lines.

Comment: It could be many things, off the top of my head I would check the architecture of the apache binary vs the arch of your machine.  Run `file /usr/sbin/httpd` and compare the type of binary to the output of `uname -m`.  If they match I would then do an strace of the start commands.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen You're right, I have provided more details. I have not upgraded any software recently and made any other changes. One day  I have just noticed Apache is down. The server was working fine.

Comment: @d34dh0r53 You see the output of both commands match. I did do strace but unfortunately my qualification does not allow me to read it.

Comment: @lush can you please run `strace /etc/init.d/httpd start` and provide the output?  You may need to put it in a pastebin, I'm not sure what serverfaults character limits are.

Comment: The best way is make it generate a core dump and debug with `gdb`: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configure-apache-web-server-for-core-dump.html.

Comment: Here is the strace output: http://zalil.ru/32052502 Just open the link and wait for several seconds for automatic download. I have tried configuring core dumps but Apache does not create them for some reasons. I did check Apache can write to the dumps directory.

Comment: Did you set `ulimit -c` to `unlimited`?

Comment: Yes, I set it, but it is still 1024; please check the gdb output [here](http://zalil.ru/32053513). It looks to be a problem with Zend. I have tried commenting all lines in php.ini with no result.

Comment: It seems the issue has been fixed. I have added both /usr/lib64/php/modules and /usr/lib64/httpd/modules to my php.ini. The segmentation fault was related to incorrect loaded php5 module. Thanks all for help, I will plus all comments.